# Can we show that the probability measure $\nu$ is just the Dirac measure supported on the measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Question: Fix the coupling $\pi=(Id,f)_{\#}\mu$. Can we show that the disintegration is $\delta_{f(x)}$?

---

My proof:

Note that for all measurable sets $B\subset R$,
$$
\nu(B)=\mu(f^{-1}(B))=\int_R 1[x\in f^{-1}(B)]\mu(dx)=\int_R \delta_{f(x)}(B)\mu(dx).
$$
Also,
$$
\nu(B)=\pi(R\times B)=\int_R \pi_x(B)\mu(dx).
$$

So
$$
0=\int_R \delta_{f(x)}(B)\mu(dx)-\int_R \pi_x(B)\mu(dx)=\int_R (\delta_{f(x)}(B)-\pi_x(B))\mu(dx)
$$

Does it mean
$$
\pi_x=\delta_{f(x)} \mbox{ -$\mu$ a.s. }
$$
for some measurable functions $f$?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear. You're given that $\nu = f_{\#}\mu$ and you ask if $\pi_x = \delta_{f(x)}$? Well, the answer is yes and no. The disintegration is derived from a coupling, not from marginals. One of them is $\pi = g_{\#} \mu$, where $g(x) = (x,f(x))$, and its disintegration is $\pi_x = \delta_{f(x)}$. But there may be many other couplings.

Comment: @zhoraster Yes, that is my question.

Comment: What do you mean the answer is yes and no?

Comment: But the reverse is true, if $\pi_x=\delta_{f(X)}$, then $\nu=f_{\#}\mu$, right?

Comment: Too many questions at once... 1) The answer is (was) yes and no, because it is positive for one particular coupling and is negative for others (if there are). 2) The reverse is true. 3) You proof shows precisely the reverse. 3) You're trying to trick yourself or others by putting these $X$ and $Y$ there. You have to decide, whether you speak about $\mu$ and $\nu$ or about the vector $(X,Y) = (X,f(X))$. These are very different stories. In general, there are many couplings. You can take $X\sim \mu = \nu$. One coupling is (the distribution of) $(X,X)$. Another one is $\mu\times \mu$.

Comment: 4) Your argument shows that. The disintegration is not unique though (it is defined modulo $\mu$-null sets).

Comment: @zhoraster  Thank you! Can we show how to prove for $\pi=g_{\#}\mu$ where $g(x)=(x, f(x)),$ then $\pi_x=\delta_{f(x)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $g(x) = (x,f(x))$.
If $\pi_x = \delta_{f(x)}$, then, for any measurable $A$ and $B$,
$$
\int_{A} \pi_x(B) \mu(dx) = \int_{A} \mathbb{1}_{f(x)\in B} \mu(dx) = \mu(\{x\in A: f(x)\in B\})\\ = \mu(\{x: (x,f(x))\in A\times B\}) = \mu(g^{-1}(A\times B)) = g_{\#}\mu(A\times B),
$$
which shows that $\pi_x$ is the disintegration of the coupling $\pi  = g_{\#}\mu$.

Comment: No, this is not what I want. I try to prove $\pi_x=\delta_{f(x)}$. How to prove that? you just rewrite my proof....

Comment: I add one more sentence in my proof. Do you think work for proof of $\pi_x=\delta_{f(x)} \mbox{ -$\mu$ a.s. }?$

Comment: @Hermi, the disintegration is unique modulo $\mu$.